# Using CakePdf data not showing

Tags: cakephp, pdf-generation, cakephp-2.3

I am in a problem with `CakePDF`. I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. I setup everything alright, bootstrap & core files are ok.

Now, I want to generate many pdf files and download them. Downloading is ok, but when I download the files, I see that the generated pdf files say that `Undefined $data`, where I send `$data` to the view file.

Here is my Controller code:

```
App::uses('CakePdf', 'CakePdf.pdf');

// ...

public function createPdf($id) {
    $data = $this->DBTable->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'DBTable.id' => $id
        )
    ));

    $CakePdf = new CakePdf();
    $path = APP . DS . 'pdf' . DS;

    foreach($data as $key => $var) {
        $CakePdf->template('create', 'default');

        $this->set('var', $var);

        $this->pdfConfig = array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => $var['id'] . ".pdf"
        );
        $CakePdf->write($path . $var['id'] . ".pdf");
    }
}
```

Here, I am downloading the files some other way, not related to this problem, because downloading is ok. When I run this, all files are downloaded, and when I see the files, they say "Udefined var", looks like they didn't receive and variable called "$var".

I put the view file & the layout exactly where ceeram said.

What should I do now ? Please help me.

Comment: What if you create the `CakePDF` instance inside the foreach loop?

Comment: Nope, same result. I checked it right now and it shows the same error. @Holt

Comment: Where do you reference the `$var`? In `create` view or `default` lauout?

Comment: In 'create' view, not in the 'default' layout. @lp1051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I got a solution to this. In the `Controller function` :

```
$data=$this->ModelName->find('all');
$CakePdf=new CakePdf();
$CakePdf->template('view_file','default');
$this->pdfConfig=array('orientation'=>'portrait','filename'=>$data['name']);
$CakePdf->viewVars(array('data'=>$data));
$CakePdf->write($path.$data['name'].".pdf");
```

Here, we have to store `view_file.ctp` in `View/Pdf/`, and `default` in `View/Layouts/pdf/`, where `view_file.ctp` is the view file which we want to convert in `pdf`, and `default` is the  `layout` for this specific view file.

Here, `viewVars()` function passes the `data` to the view file, just like :

```
$this->set->('data',$data);
```

Let me know if anything is not clear here.
Thanks.